# Why the node.js project using typescript needs to declare ResolveJsonModule to be true into typescript compiler option when it imports json file?

Tags: node.js, json, typescript

Title is description.

I want to know about the reason of that.
Please let me know about it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Advisory Answer**

I've found the answer from [this reference site](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/importing-json-modules-in-typescript).

```
// We no longer need the "use strict" directive since
// all ECMAScript modules implicitly use strict mode.

import * as express from "express";
import * as config from "./config.json";

const app = express();

app.listen(config.server.nodePort, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${config.server.nodePort} ...`);
});
```

> we get a type error in line 2. TypeScript doesn't let us import a JSON
>   module out of the box, just like that. This was a conscious design
>   decision made by the TypeScript team: pulling in large JSON files
>   could potentially consume a lot of memory, which is why we need to opt
>   into that feature by enabling the --resolveJsonModule compiler